# mercurial ignore .zip files in whole repository

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

i am using Mercurial for version controlling. I am trying to ignore zip files in the repository, my hgignore file is in the root directory of project

i got the codes below from http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#patterns.

```
syntax: glob
**.zip

syntax: regexp
re:.*\.zip$
```

But these doesnt work for me.

i also tried

```
hg addremove
```

and

```
hg forget -I '*'
```

but it didnt help. Can you tell me how can properly ignore zip files from the repository?
Thanks for help.

EDIT

My problem was the zip files were already added to repository. I first forgot them and committed. Now it ignores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply writing `*.zip` inside `.hgignore` will do this. The patterns inside `.hgignore` are not rooted, so `*.zip` would match a zip archive no matter where it appears.

Comment: @user2314575: No, you need to `hg forget` them explicitly.